# Continuous function in $\Bbb R^+\times\Bbb R^+$

Tags: general-topology

I have a question. I have to show, by using the arithmetic rules, that the function $g$ on $\Bbb R^+\times\Bbb R^+$ defined by $$g(x,y) = \big(\ln(1+x^2+y^2), \ln(1+x^3y)\big)$$ is continuous.

How must I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Let $g_1(x,y)=\ln(1+x^2+y^2)$ and $g_2(x,y)= \ln (1+x^3y)$ for $x,y >0$

Then: $g$ is continuous iff $g_1$ and $g_2$ are continuous.

$\ln$ is continuous and the fuctions $1+x^2+y^2$ and $1+x^3y$ are continuous, hence $g_1$ and $g_2$ are continuous, therefore $g$ is continuous.

Comment: Thank you, but how do you prove that the function ( 1+x^2 +y^2 and 1+x^3y) are continuous?